# Curl -> Xpath -> returns a string, need to further parse to return a 3-4 digit number

Tags: php, regex, curl, xpath

this is probably a very stupid question as I am very new to php. Basically I am attempting to create some nice 'automation' for a competition website I maintain.

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.pdga.com/player/73761";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$class = 'current-rating';
$divs = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), '
'), ' $class ')]");
foreach($divs as $div) {
echo $div->nodeValue;
}
?>
```

This currently returns

```
Current Rating: 949 (as of 06-Dec-2016)
```

I would want to further parse it so it gives the number 949 (in this case).

Effectively what I am attempting to do is as these ratings update every month, my website would update automatically when this number changes. Also, this number can range from 750-1050 so that would need to be taken into account here.

Thank you for your help ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using preg_match() which will use a regular expression to match what you want.

e.g.

```
foreach($divs as $div) {
    preg_match('/Current Rating:\s+(\d+)/', $div->nodeValue, $results);
    echo $results[1];
}
```

Comment: damn that was too easy for you :) Ill try harder next time. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Uhh just a further query if you would also have a clue about it as it is my next problem.

I'm basically making a handicap system based off that number. So eg. 
800-850=-10, 851-900=0, 901-950=+5 for instance. How would you go about doing that. 

All I would need to present is the single digit.

Comment: You could try creating an array for your thresholds with the lower and upper limits and the handicap score. Then loop through your thresholds to see if your score fits within the current threshold. It's a bit hard to write an example in the comment section and it's best you try to do it yourself. have a look a multidimensional arrays, they should help http://webcheatsheet.com/php/multidimensional_arrays.php